# Common Bootstrapper for IoC

Tags: c#, ioc-container, bootstrapping

I am looking for active library to bootstrap my application. 
Currently I am using  Bootstrapper from http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/.
But it wasn't updated for second year so I am a little bit suspicious. there are 13 forks from the project and all of them have the same name, that does not help when search in google. 
Are there any "Common Bootstrapper" projects similar to CommonLogging?

Comment: What you call bootstrapping is what most IoC containers provide themselves. Perhaps that's why the project was abandoned - if it ended up taking as much code as the IoC container (or more, if reflection was used), there wouldn't be any point to it. BTW CommonLogging abstract the *interface* of logging, not the configuration of individual libraries.

Comment: Thanks for comment. There is one line of code to initialize and start your app using the project. Bootstrapper.With.Autofac().Including.Assembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (Customer))).Start(); I am looking for abstract interface of bootstrapping wich is commonly used.

Comment: Which takes more characters than AutoFac's `.RegisterAssemblyTypes(myAssembly)`, doesn't allow filtering of types or changing what gets mapped like `.AsImplementedInterfaces();` does. You are looking for commonalities in the one part that *isn't* common among containers - how to configure them, especially the non-obvious cases.